# Team Foundation Serivce (TFS) and running visual studio instance

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have created a repo using TFS (cloud) on www.visualstudio.com
I created my repo as on something as myproject.visualstudio.com and when trying to run or click on following link:

**Open new instance of Visual Studio** it throws an error as

> Cannot open file vstfs:///Framework/TeamProject/..... Verify that the
>   file still exists and then try again

I searched here on SOV and also on MSDN and found a thread on MSDN forum but it was about some services pack and updates.

Has anybody ever used this service?

Thanks.

Comment: What browser are you using? Why not just open Visual Studio and configure TFS from the "TEAM" menu instead?

Comment: FF and IE browser I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you already created project on yourAccountName.visualstudio.com

Then, if you are using VS2010, install recommended update SP1 [VS2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

After that (it might take a while as long as 30 min), just start VS2010, on start page just click Connect To Team Foundation Server, then on "Select a team Foundation Server" click on "Servers", then "Add", and in "Name or URL of Team Foundation Server" just paste URL of your AccountName such as: "https://yourAccountName.visualstudio.com" (withouth quotes). then you jsut click OK and that's it. Your VS2010 should be now connected with your account at visualstudio.com

This is a bit of a manual method but it works :)

You can find more about it in this MSDN blog [Team Foundation Service Preview – Connect Visual Studio 2010 to Your TFS Preview Account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2011/12/07/connect-visual-studio-2010-to-your-tfs-preview-account.aspx?PageIndex=2)

Answer (score 1):

there is a solution I just found which walks me through IDE.

1. Run VS2012 Under "Start" in VS 2012 click on "Connect to Team Foundation Server ..."
2. It will popup a dialog so then in bottom of dialog/form there is link as "Sign In", click on it
3. Enter your user-name and password Now, you are connected to the server and can view
   all your Repositories

P.S. don't forget to add your server URL on the list TFS in your IDE provides.